# How do I call my dialog before multiple async/await starts and close after those calls are completed?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want call my `dialog` box before the sequence of multiple `async/await` calls. This is my code:

```
document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();

if(condition 1 is true){
    if(condition 2 is true){
        (async()=>{
             await f1();
        })();
    }
}

if(condition 3 is true){
    if(condition 4 is true){
        (async()=>{
             await f2();
        })();
    }
}

if(condition 5 is true){
    if(condition 6 is true){
        (async()=>{
             await f3();
        })();
    }
}

document.getElementById("dialog").close();
```

Upon executing the code, the dialog opens and closes instantly before the `async/await` calls even complete. How do I close the dialog only when all the server calls are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only code that will wait for the promise to resolve is other code in the same `async` function, after the `await`. Code outside the `async` function will not wait. So your tiny `async` functions do next to nothing, because there is no code after their `await`s.

You need to write this code as one large async function.

```
const someFunction = async () => {
  document.getElementById("dialog").showModal();

  if(condition 1 is true){
    if(condition 2 is true){
      await f1();
    }
  }

  if(condition 3 is true){
    if(condition 4 is true){
      await f2();
    }
  }

  if(condition 5 is true){
    if(condition 6 is true){
      await f3();
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("dialog").close();
}
```